# CEF C++ program not rendering in Ubuntu

Tags: c++, gtk, chromium-embedded

I am trying to build and run a CEF application on Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS. The application is built using CEF (Chromium Embedded Framework), in C++. I have previously built it on Debian 8.11 with success. The issue is as is shown on the screenshot [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GwcNl.png). Instead of being just a copy of whatever was behind it, the screen should contain a mini custom web browser. I am pretty sure there is something wrong with the rendering process but I can not describe it in more detail.

The differences I noted are following:

- gcc/g++: Debian - 4.9.2 | Ubuntu - 4.9.3
- libgtk2.0-0: Debian - 2.24.25-3+deb8u2 | Ubuntu - 2.24.30-1ubuntu1.16.04.2
  libgtk-3-0
- libgtk-3-0: Debian - 3.14.5-1+deb8u1 | Ubuntu - 3.18.9-1ubuntu3.3

I would be more than happy to provide more info if needed.

Comment: Can you check if browser and renderer process got created successfully? are you building cefsimple or cefclient or you have written your own app to launch it?

Comment: @Sanjeev It is an application written based on cefsimple and/or cefclient, I believe. I am trying to check if renderer and browser processes were created and started correctly. Meanwhile, I detected that there are loads of processes on Ubuntu, where there are only 4 on Debian. Maybe a screenshot with their command line arguments would be helpful?

Comment: Number of processes should not be different because of Ubuntu, eventually those should be same in both. Yes screenshot will help. What URL you are trying to load? try to load a simple page present in local server or static page and let me know if it is getting rendered.

Comment: The window looks the same with both local server and google.com. You can find the screenshots of the processes [here](https://imgur.com/a/Y6VHCVH) for Ubuntu and [here](https://imgur.com/a/GG98YEQ) for Debian. I executed ps combined with grep.

Comment: Also, I noticed that the cef debugging server was up on Ubuntu when I started the application.

Comment: I now tried building on Debian and copying and running the same binary on Ubuntu. This tells me that the shared libraries (that are a part of the project) are built correctly, since I only copied the executable, not the shared libraries.

Comment: Nothing is shown in the screenshots you mentioned in the comment. You have to mention the full details/steps of building and executing it. Without knowing such details It's difficult to analyze what went wrong with you.

Comment: I am unsure if I am allowed to disclose the build scripts since it's company's IP.

Comment: Understood. Are you running cef in ubuntu desktop or in an embedded box running ubuntu? Do your Ubuntu platform have any sort of Layer manager?

Comment: Ubuntu, just like Debian, runs on a Virtual Machine using VMWare Workstation Player. It's Ubuntu Desktop. I don't know what a layer manager is (tried Googling but to no avail).